# is galaxy s10 (xxxhdpi) scaled 4x or 3.5x?

Tags: android, screen-density, density-independent-pixel

https://material.io/resources/devices/ (which is not maintained anymore) has

```
3.5x for xxxhdpi  google pixel xl
4x for xxxhdpi galaxy s8
```

https://material.io/blog/device-metrics lists only `4x` for xxxhdpi

https://reactnative.dev/docs/pixelratio lists only `3.5x` for xxxhdpi

So it's very confusing, galaxy s10 has 550ppi and falls into `xxxhdpi`
Is it 3.5x scaled or 4x scaled?

Is it different depending on whether we are on native android or react-native android?